# How To check whether mobile supports flash LED or not in mainfest.xml file

Tags: android

well i have used :
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
 but this checks for camera . but i want to check whether Flash Led is there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />`, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features).